# include move_group_interface

Tags: moveit, ros-kinetic, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm running ROS Kinetic on Ubuntu 16.04.

So I was trying to make my own MoveIt interface, after experimenting and getting comfortable with the demo.launch created by the moveit setup assistant.

But I immediatly ran into a problem, I can't figure out how to include the move group interface.
This is the line I'm using to try and include the move_group_interface:

```
#include <moveit/planning_interface/move_group_interface.h>
```

But whatever I try, I keep getting the following error:

```
fatal error: moveit/planning_interface/move_group_interface.h: No such file or directory
```

I'm guessing it has something to do with my CMakeLists.txt, but I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(robotarm_moveit)

## Compile as C++11, supported in ROS Kinetic and newer
add_compile_options(-std=c++11)

## Find catkin macros and libraries
## if COMPONENTS list like find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS xyz)
## is used, also find other catkin packages
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  roscpp
  moveit_ros_planning_interface
)

catkin_package(
  CATKIN_DEPENDS
    roscpp
    moveit_ros_planning_interface
)

include_directories(
)

## Declare a C++ library
add_library(${PROJECT_NAME}
  src/robotarm_moveit_interface.cpp
)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME}_node src/robotarm_moveit_interface.cpp)

add_dependencies(${PROJECT_NAME}_node ${${PROJECT_NAME}_EXPORTED_TARGETS} ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS})


install(DIRECTORY launch DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_SHARE_DESTINATION}
  PATTERN "setup_assistant.launch" EXCLUDE)
install(DIRECTORY config DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_SHARE_DESTINATION})
```

Maybe somebody can spot what I'm doing wrong here?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/306640/include-move_group_interface/) by [Squid](https://answers.ros.org/users/38189/squid/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2018-10-24

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try

```
   #include <moveit/move_group_interface/move_group_interface.h>
```

The MoveGroupInterface is inside the planning_interface namespace, but its header is located in the above directory.

---

Originally posted by [pcoenen](https://answers.ros.org/users/30604/pcoenen/) with karma: 249 on 2018-10-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Squid](https://answers.ros.org/users/38189/squid/) on 2018-10-25**:
Doesn't seem to work, I get the same error.

Should I maybe just try and reinstall MoveIt? The demo is working fine so I'm not sure whether that could be the problem?

**Comment by [pcoenen](https://answers.ros.org/users/30604/pcoenen/) on 2018-10-25**:
Did you remove `#include <moveit/planning_interface/move_group_interface.h>`?

**Comment by [Squid](https://answers.ros.org/users/38189/squid/) on 2018-10-25**:
Yup, what I mean by same error is that instead of

```
fatal error: moveit/planning_interface/move_group_interface.h: No such file or directory
```

I just get

```
fatal error: moveit/move_group_interface/move_group_interface.h: No such file or directory
```

**Comment by [pcoenen](https://answers.ros.org/users/30604/pcoenen/) on 2018-10-25**:
Try that in CMakeLists.txt:

```
include_directories(
  include
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)
```

**Comment by [Squid](https://answers.ros.org/users/38189/squid/) on 2018-10-25**:
That seemed to do the trick!

After I added that, I got some undefined references, but those where easily solvable by uncommeting the target_link_libraries() section in my CMakeLists.txt

**Comment by [jack zhang](https://answers.ros.org/users/128081/jack-zhang/) on 2022-12-19**:
Did you resolve it ,I also met the  same error.